# Adding library (Smack) to Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Since I need to make some changes to the [Smack](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) library, I want to add the Smack as a library to my Android Studio project. I've download the ZIP file from the [Smack Github repository](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack), and did the following steps -- as I found while searching for solutions

(1) Created a new folder `libs` in my project root folder and copied the extracted and renamed folder `/Smack` into `libs`. So it's now the following structure:

```
root/libs/Smack/
```

(2) I edited my `settings.gradle` in the root folder to

```
include ':app'
include ':libs:Smack'
```

(3) Via `File -> Project Structure -> Modules app -> Dependencies`, I've added `:libs:Smack` as module dependency

(4) I've added the following line to `root/app/build.gradle`

```
compile project(':libs:Smack')
```

According to most sources I found online, this should be it. However, I got an error that `Gradle project sync failed`. In more detail I get:

```
/path-to-root/libs/Smack/build.gradle
Error:(42, 0) Project with path ':smack-integration-test' could not be found in project ':libs:Smack'.
```

When I look into the file and line it says `project(':smack-integration-test')`. Somehow this cannot be found. However, there is a folder `libs/Smack/smack-integration-test`. It looks pretty straightforward, but I seem to miss something crucial here.

**EDIT:** Android Studio actually supports importing Gradle Projects: `File -> New -> New Module` opens a dialog window where I select `Import Gradle Project` where I have to select the source directory of, here, Smack. Doing this makes all the correct include statements in `settings.gradle`.

However, no I get the error:

```
Error:(386, 0) Could not get unknown property 'clirr' for project ':smack-integration-test' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Since I'm not familiar enough with Gradle, I have no idea what this might mean, and my Google search also didn't advance me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't add the project in this way, you can keep it a separate project out of your project folder structure, you would modify it and build it. The simplest way is to copy the build jar file(s) into your project and include it into gradle:

For jar, create the libs folder in your project and copy the file there, gradle including works like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) // for all of the jars in the libs folder
compile files('libs/xyz.jar') // for a specific file
```

In particular for the Smack project, you can do it with a

```
gradle assemble
```

in it's root folder

The ouput jar(s) are in each specific folder, per example for android I see:

> smack-android\build\libs\
>
> smack-android-extensions\build\libs\

Comment: I looked into it. But creating a JAR file from a Gradle project seems not exactly straightforward. I might have to go this way, I was just hoping to have quick solution even if it's dirty since it's only for testing purposes.

Comment: I done a test locally with the Smack library and it's quite straight forward, if you run the gradle command in it's root it will build all the sub-projects. From there you can pick the jar (s) relevant for you from the build folders

Comment: I've accepted the answer, since made progress this way. I was able to create the varies jar files and imported it into my project. However, replace the `compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0'` lines with the respective `compile files('libs/...jar')` lines threw errors in my source code. I assume there are different versions.

Comment: It also can be related to the jar(s) included, like missing something

Comment: I don't know. One method now throws an exception, which didn't have to be caught so far. Another method complains about the wrong signature -- one input parameter was first a String now some class. A lot of these differences across the working source code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'd recommend creating a multi-module build out of the two projects. This will likely not work as expected. It's likely you'll need to add most/all of the modules in the [smack settings.gradle](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/settings.gradle) to your own `settings.gradle`. If you really want to do this, I suggest you use [prezi-pride](https://github.com/prezi/pride) which manages this from command line.

I'm not an android user so not sure which versions(s) of Gradle the android plugin works with. If android supports Gradle 3.1+ then you can use the new [composite build support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). This is by far the cleanest solution and I recommend this approach

Another solution is to build the projects separately and in your project do

```
compile fileTree(dir: '../smack/project-1/build/lib', include: '*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: '../smack/project-2/build/lib', include: '*.jar')
// etc
```

Yet another solution is to [publish the smack artifacts to maven local](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:install) and reference them from there in your project. This would likely be the second best solution if you can't use composite build

Comment: I've added all modules to my `settings.gradle` like `include ':libs:Smack:smack-integration-test'`, and also added all as module dependencies (cf. (3) in my question). No change, same error.

Comment: As I said... it might not work. Try (1) composite build, (2) mavenLocal() or (3) prezi-pride

Comment: I kind of solved my initial problem, but stumbled upon the next one (see my edit in original question). The automated import did indeed put all the includes in the `settings.gradle` as you have suggested, only the format was different than my attempt.

Comment: Your idea of joining the builds together is a bad idea. Are you using Gradle 3.1+? Use a composite build and get on with life! Failing that, use `mavenLocal()`

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution for your problem but a possibly even nicer workaround could be the following:

[jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/) provides you with the ability to add GitHub Repositories to your project as Gradle Dependencies, thus allowing you to omit the process of manually adding the jar.
How to achieve that is best described by JitPack itself.
In short:
Add the JitPack Repository to your build.gradle:

```
    repositories {
        ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
```

You can now add the GitHub Repo as a Dependency:

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.igniterealtime:Smack:-SNAPSHOT'
    }
```

After refreshing your project you should be able to use the API as expected.

Comment: Will I be able to modify the source code of Smack? So far, I include Smack by adding something like `compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0'` as dependency in `build.gradle`. This works well enough, but I cannot modify the source code.

Comment: No - Smack would be added to the project as a jar

Comment: Editing the source code of the API doesn't seem to be good practice anyhow - personally, I'd just go with Kotlin and extend the API with the desired functions ;)

Comment: I agree. It was never meant to be a permanent solution. I just was just for testing purposes to confirm if a connection problem I have is indeed (partly) due to minor detail in the Smack implementation. Just so I know I'm on the right track.

Comment: `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.igniterealtime:Smack:-SNAPSHOT`